# How can I alter a query adding an OR clause for a relational field?

Tags: 8, views

I have an "Event" node type with a number of fields: title, date, location, description, etc.

Because a number of events are similar, we added a "Parent event" entity reference field. Child events inherit fields (e.g. location, description) from the parent, if set.

We have a block that displays all of the events for a location, using a contextual filter. The problem is that the child events have an empty location – it is inherited from the parent event when we render the event page.

How can I adjust the view query to select all events with *either* the contextual location ID, *or* with a parent that has the location ID?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

- Add a *relationship* for content referenced from the entity reference field.
- Add a *contextual filter* for the entity reference field, using the *content ID* from the URL as the value. This includes events that have the location set directly.
- Add a *contextual filter* for the entity reference field, using the *content ID* from the URL as the value, **using the relationship**. This includes events are related to an event that has the location set.

Unfortunately, the contextual filter WHERE group uses `AND` by default, so no results are returned, so we have to change the `type` in the WHERE clause.

```
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function my_module_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, Sql $query) {
  if ($view->id() === 'events') {
    if ($view->current_display === 'block_2') {
      $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
    }
  }
}
```

If there are more contextual filters, you have to create a new OR where group with the fields, and remove them from group `0`.

```
$group0 = &$query->where[0];

// Create a new OR group.
$group_id = $query->setWhereGroup('OR');

// Copy the conditions to the new where group.
$query->addWhereExpression(
    $group_id,
    $group0['conditions'][1]['field'],
    $group0['conditions'][1]['value']
);
$query->addWhereExpression(
    $group_id,
    $group0['conditions'][2]['field'],
    $group0['conditions'][2]['value']
);

// Remove from group 0
unset($group0['conditions'][1]);
unset($group0['conditions'][2]);
```